# Cisco express forwarding

Tags: cef, asics

I'm studying CEF and I'm confused with these terms : Route processor, forwarding engine, centralized and distributed forwarding, npu

So my questions is

1. is the RP a hardware component or an ios task running on the cpu
2. is distributed forwarding = hardware CEF
   And centralized forwarding = software CEF
3. I'm asking if anyone has useful materials for this.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the context of CEF, the route processor is a hardware component.
2. When the route processor has all information it uses *centralized forwarding*. When it requires the help from line cards it uses *distributed forwarding*. CEF is always done in hardware.
3. See [Cisco's explanation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/12000-series-routers/47321-ciscoef.html?dtid=osscdc000283). The main point of CEF is to speed up forwarding as much as possible, eliminating ARP table lookups and such.

Comment: 1/In case of dCEF what's happen to punted paquets, is RP who is gonna be in charge or the cpu 2/ what are other RP tasks, do routing protocols run on it 3/ is gigabit route processor (GRP) same as TCAM

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know the full context, but RP could mean just the hardware or it could be referencing all the software that runs on it, collectively.  It definitely isn't referring to just one IOS task/process, though.
2. dCEF refers to linecards having a routing table and look-up hardware on them.  I think the Cisco 7500 series was one of the first Cisco products with a layer-3 dCEF functionality.  Centralized Forwarding does not mean software CEF.  It's describing a router with one hardware lookup engine (usually on a supervisor card) and the other linecards send packets to that central one for look-up.